# cant get sharepoint powershell admin to work - term not recognised

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

```
 > set-spotenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false                                        
 set-spotenant: The term 'set-spotenant' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.

> Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential me@domain.com
set-spotenant: The term 'set-spotenant' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

I installed the latest powershell using homebrew on m1 mac.  This worked.

% pwsh --version
PowerShell 7.1.3

Then I installed the power shell extension.

I tried:

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -Scope CurrentUser
```

and later

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -RequiredVersion 16.0.21213.12000    


 Get-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -ListAvailable | Select Name,Version
```

returns:

```
 Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell 16.0.21411.12000
 Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell 16.0.21213.12000
```

Comment: You have to use the PnP module for [cross-platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) support.

Comment: Thanks, tried that, get same issue.  Tried exiting re-opening powershell

Comment: If the PnP module isn't working with it's cmdlets (note: they won't be the same name), then you will need to report the issue on the [GitHub site](https://github.com/pnp/powershell).